# Compare a string from richtextbox to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, richtextbox

I have written a Windows Forms application in C# and connected it with Microsoft SQL Server where I store some strings. I want to write in a richtextbox and the program should compare these words of richtextbox with words stored in database. If that word is found in the database, the program should do nothing, but if it is not found, the word in the richtextbox should be underlined with red color. Like the spellchecking feature in Microsoft word. I don't know how to do that - please help me.

```
private void RichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT phonetic,grammar, meaning, sentence FROM dictionaryTable WHERE N'word' LIKE'%" + this.richTextBox.Text.Trim() + "%'", con);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    try
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start parameterizing your queries. This is a classic anti-pattern that is wide open to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/ You have a second anti-pattern here I call try/squelch where you go through the trouble of catching an error and then throw it away as if nothing went wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  you might want to lower case both text to begin with.

Comment: Apart from the huge injection issue, @DaImTo ?

Comment: [SqlCommand.Parameters Property - Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8#examples)

Comment: I would use the built in spellchecking ability of the rich text box instead of trying to roll your own. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.spellcheck?view=netframework-4.8